# How do I manage minion roles with salt-stack pillars?

Tags: salt-stack

I'm trying to understand how to use Salt with roles like Chef can be used, but I have some holes in my understanding that reading lots of docs has failed to fill at this point.

The principle issue is that I'm trying to manage roles with Salt, like Chef does, but I don't know how to appropriately set the pillar value. What I want to do is assign, either by script or by hand, a role to a vagrant box and then have the machine install the appropriate files on it.

What I don't understand is how I can set something that will tell salt-master what to install on the box given the particular role I want it to be. I tried setting a

```
salt.pillar('site' => 'my_site1')
```

in the Vagrantfile and then checking it in the salt state `top.sls` file with

```
{{ pillar.get('site') == 'my_site1'
  -<do some stuff>
```

But this doesn't work. What's the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, it becomes easier when matching ids in pillars.  First, set the minion_id to be something identifiable, for example `test-mysite1-db` (and above all unique. Hence the username initials at the end as an example.
in the `top.sls` in `/srv/pillar` do

```
base:
 '<regex_matching_id1>':
   - webserver.mysite1
 '<regex_matching_id2>':
   - webserver.mysite2
```

And then in `webserver.mysite1` put

```
role : mysiteid1
```

for example.

Then in `/srv/state/top.sls` you can then match with jinja or just with

```
base:
 'role:mysiteid1':
   - match: pillar
   - state
   - state2
```

Hence, roles derived from the ids. Works for me.

Comment: Thanks for your example although I find it a bit confusing. Where did `webserver_role:hrbdf` come from? Is it specified in `/srv/pillar/webserver/mysite1` instead of `role: mysiteid1`?

Comment: @span Apologies -- complete copy-paste error. Fixed now. Please ask further if anything's unclear.

Comment: Thanks, looks very nice :)

Answer (score 2):

How to implement and utilize roles is intentionally vague in the salt documentation. Every permutation of how to implement, and then how to use, roles carries with it trade-offs -- so it is up to you to decide how to do it.

In your scenario I can assume that you want rather singular 'roles' or purposes associated with a virtualbox VM, and then have state.highstate run the states associated with that role.

If the above is correct, I would go with grains rather than pillars while learning salt for the sake of simplicity.

#### On each minion

Just add `role: webserver` to /etc/salt/grains and restart the salt-minion.

#### On the master

Update /srv/state/top.sls file to then associate state .sls files with that grain.

```
base:
  '*':
    - fail2ban

  role:webserver:
    - match: grain
    - nginx

  role:dbserver:
    - match: grain
    - mysql
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer. I've just tried this and upon executing `vagrant provision` I'm getting "Unable to render top file. No targets found"

Comment: Is there some formatting missing here? Is there supposed to be a `base:` name at the top?

Comment: there is a missing colon, e.g. 'role:webmaster':